# Does $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ exist?

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

Let $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$ be a continuous map, if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|\,dx$ exists, then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ exists, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you are dealing with the Riemann integral here. Yes, that is correct, assuming that the restriction of $f$ to any interval $[a,b]$ is Riemann-integrable. That's a consequence of [Cauchy's criterion](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cauchy_criteria#Cauchy_criterion_for_real-valued_functions).

Comment: +1 Cauchy criterion.  Students should remember that this is not just a trick, it is useful.